# MySQL get interval records

Tags: mysql

Are there any solutions on MySQL script to filter the results with specific interval number.

For example, if I have 100,000 records in database and I'd like to get only the record number 1000, 2000, 3000, etc. (step by 1000).

I could do this on server side script by getting the entire results (e.g. 100,000) and use syntax like:

```
for($i=0, $i <= 100,000, $i = $i+1000) $filterResult[] = $record[$i];
```

However, as you may see, it would pull stress to the system as 100,000 records will need to generated first.

Are there any solutions that could complete from database script? Please note that, primary key may not start with 1 - 100,000 as the results based on some condition in where clause.

Your help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  id % 1000 = 0
```

But it seems like you don't want to rely on the primary key value, but rather the row ranking of a result set.

In that case, you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
       SELECT     *, @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank
       FROM       tbl
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0) var_init
       WHERE      column1 = value AND
                  column2 = value
       ) a
WHERE  a.rank % 1000 = 0
```

Where `column1 = value AND column2 = value` is just a placeholder for whatever filtration you're doing in your query.

Comment: Thanks Zene. However, I can't rely on ID as it's not run in numeric order. e.g. the first 10 records may have id 199,425,122,111,....

Comment: @ZaneBien Does it matter they are not in order - adding an order by will cause a file sort after and your first query would work just fine.

Comment: @ZaneBien Thank you very much Zane, it works like a charm and processed very quick.